# Issues passing a List of Data Frames as a Parameter to a Function in R

Tags: r, list, function

I have created two functions in R

svm_class: This function performs SVM classification on a formula for a given data frame. It returns the misclassification rate.

```
svm_class<-function(form,db){
  set.seed(123)
  var<-form[[2]];var<-as.character(var)
  split<-caTools::sample.split(db, SplitRatio = 0.75)
  training_set<-subset(db, split == TRUE)
  test_set<-subset(db, split == FALSE)
  mod<-e1071::svm(formula(form),data = training_set,kernel = 'linear',
                  type = 'C-classification')
  y_pred<-predict(mod, newdata = test_set[!names(test_set) %in% var])
  cm<-table(Actual=test_set[,var], Predicted=y_pred)
  mis_rate<-1-sum(diag(cm)/sum(cm))
  return(mis_rate)
}
```

resampling: This function generates multiple samples of a data frame and stores them in a list.

```
resampling <- function(n,N,rep = TRUE,db) {
  db$id_sample <-  1:nrow(db)
  id_sample <- 1:nrow(db)
  if (rep == FALSE & n*N > length(id_sample)){
    return("Error: Not posible without repetition due to sample size and number of iterations selected")
  }
  list_db <- vector("list", length = N)
  if (N > 10000){
    print("WARNING: Not posible to generate a seed per repetition. Some seeds will be repeated.")
    seeds <- sample(0:10000, N, replace = TRUE)
  } else {
    seeds <- sample(0:10000, N, replace = FALSE)
  }
  for (i in 1:N) {
    set.seed(seeds[i])
    samp <- sample(id_sample, n)
    data_samp <- db[db$id_sample %in% samp,]
    if (rep == FALSE){
      id_sample <- id_sample[!id_sample %in% samp]
    }
    list_db[[i]] <- data_samp
  }
  return(list_db)
}
```

Now, I'm having trouble using the list obtained from the `resampling` function as input for the `svm_class` function. Could someone please help me understand how to correctly apply `svm_class` to each element of the list obtained from `resampling` and store the results in a new list?

Comment: You could use `lapply(list_db, svm_class)` but then what is your end goal with `mis_rate`?

Comment: will collaps all of them into a vector or a df. how can I introduce the parameters in the second function. I get: argument "db" is missing, with no default

Comment: `lapply(list_db, svm_class,arg1=form,arg2=db)`

Comment: did it with a loop instead... thanks